# Picking different random elements from int array each time in iteration?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have an int vector such as `int[] A = {6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2}` and I need to picking two different elements randomly during three steps, and each step should pike up different elements from other steps.

For example:

1. choose 2, 5
2. choose 6, 3
3. choose 4, 1

I try to do it, but I failed many times. I will really appreciate for any help.
here is my last code.

```
public class T8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=5,   d=2, r,  i,  j;
        int[] B = new int [d];
        Random rand=new Random(); 
        System.out.println("d = "+d);
        Integer[] A = {10,12,3,4,5};
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(A));
        for(j=0; j<d; j++){
            r = rand.nextInt(n);
            B[j] = A[r];
            System.out.print(B[j]+"   ");
            list.remove(r);
            A = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
            n=n-1;
        }

        System.out.println("");
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            System.out.print(A[j]+"   ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: One possible approach: capture each element chosen into a variable for that choice, then set its index in the original array to an invalid value, then you know what you've already chosen.  Then put all the elements back when you're done with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not optimal approach** : You can use [random.nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) and Every time when you generate the random number check whether it is unique , if not generate new random index. E.g.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class RandomPicker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2};
        Random random = new Random();
        Set<Integer> randoms = new HashSet<>();
        while (arr.length != randoms.size()) {
            int i = nextRandomIndex(arr, random, randoms);
            int j = nextRandomIndex(arr, random, randoms);
            System.out.printf("%d,%d\n", arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }

    private static int nextRandomIndex(int[] arr, Random random, Set<Integer> randoms) {
        int i = random.nextInt(arr.length);
        while (randoms.contains(i)) {
            i= random.nextInt(arr.length);
        }
        randoms.add(i);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Possible output

```
4,1
6,3
5,2
```

A better approach is to shuffle an array and then iterate over it(If you don't want to modify the array then pass a copy of original array to shuffle method). E.g.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomPicker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2};
        int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        shuffle(copy);
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d\n",copy[index], copy[++index]);
        }
    }

    private static void shuffle(int[] arr)
    {
        int index;
        int temp;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int i = arr.length - 1;
        while ( i > 0)
        {
            index = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
            temp = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* ways you could do this:

1. Copy the array elements into a `List` and then randomly remove elements from the list.
2. Use a (weak) pseudo random number generator that cycles through all indexes in a predictable fashion.
3. Create a `HashSet` of all of the elements you have returned before.
4. Use the `shuffle` method to shuffle the input array in-place, and then just return the elements one at a time starting from index `0` until you reach `length - 1`.
5. If you can't change the input array, then create an array filled with the values `0` to `length - 1`, shuffle that array, and then step through that array using its values as indexes into the first array.

@sol4me's solution (which is a hybrid of 3. and 5. above) has an interesting property.  The computational behaviour is probabilistic:

- As you reach the end of the sequence, the time taken to find and return an index that hasn't been used before grows "alarmingly".
- The theoretical worst-case behaviour is that `nextRandomIndex` never terminates.  (This can only happen if your random number generator is biased.)
- For a "perfect" random number generator, the number of iterations performed by `nextRandomIndex` is finite, but we cannot place an upper bound on it.
- For a pseudo-random number generator, the cycle length of the generator is an upper bound on the number of iterations.

---

Your attempted solution is close to the first one I suggested.  But one problem is that

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(A));
```

is creating a "view" onto the array *whose length cannot be changed*.  If you create an `ArrayList` and then *copy* the array elements to the list, you won't get the exceptions you are seeing in `remove`.

Another problem is that this:

```
    A = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

is pretty inefficient.  It should not be necessary to convert the list back into an array.  Just keep the list for next time.